# ContainerRequestFilter throwing 400 Bad Request on proper json request

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, quarkus, objectmapper

I am implementing a filter to find out any json mapping or parsing issues using ContainerRequestFilter interface. It logs error for all json parsing or mapping issues but for request which doesn't have any json validation issues it throws 400 Bad request. If I remove the filter from the code it works fine for proper json request. Below is the code for the same ..

```
 @Provider
 public class AppFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AppFilter.class);

  @Inject
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
   
   try(InputStream stream = new CloseShieldInputStream(context.getEntityStream())) {
       objectMapper.readValue(stream,AppRequest.class);
      }catch(Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(ex));
      }
    }
  }

@Path("/app")
public class MatchResource {
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Uni<Response> processRequest(AppRequest request,
                                        @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    String tranId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(TIME_ZONE_ID);
    return Uni.createFrom().item(request)
            .onItem().invoke(() -> {
                Set<ConstraintViolation<AppRequest>> violations = validator.validate(request);
                if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new RequestViolationsException(violations, 
   request.header.applicationReferenceId);
                }
  }).onFailure()
            .transform(t ->     LOG.error(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(t)));
}
```

Let me know if I am missing anything in this ..

Comment: Probably because you're reading the stream. I don't know what a `CloseShieldInputStream` is but I'm assuming, like most InputStreams, it can only be read once.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha then I would be getting Stream is closed error not the 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: You will get a 400 with any exception that occurs with the Jackson JSON provider

Comment: @PaulSamsotha But if I remove the filter it works fine for the proper json means json without any validation errors .. so I want to know what's causing this issue ..

Comment: I told you already. The stream is read by your filter. That's what's causing the error. Why would you expect it to _not_ work without the filter?

Comment: If I don't use CloseShieldInputStream  then hitting filter second time causes Stream is closed in the logs. CloseShieldInputStream   prevents this Stream getting closes as it Proxy stream that prevents the underlying input stream from being closed.

Comment: Closed and consumed are two different things. Can you verify it's not empty by the time it gets to the provider?

Comment: Filter is needed to log json mapping errors if any. I am saying if I don't use filter just to test whether my request is fine or not it works fine with the proper request and removing the filter...

Comment: I don't get what you don't understand about what I'm saying.

Comment: ok so how can I verify if the request is empty or not in this filter .. I mean which method I can use in this case to find if request is empty or not in the filter..

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the provider I guess.

Comment: try adding `catch (JsonProcessingException e)` for any Jackson JSON provider exception/errors/. maybe convert that `InputStream` to a non-stream right away before you convert it to another object.